# How do I uppercase to lowercase and vice versa COMMENTS in C

Tags: c, comments, uppercase, lowercase

Is there any way to do uppercase to lowercase and vice versa for COMMENTS?
For example:

```
*** input_file.c ***

#include <stdio.h>

/* My FIRST program */
void main(void) {
    printf("Hello world!\n"); // PRINT Message
}


*** output_file.c ***

#include <stdio.h>

/* mY first PROGRAM */
void main(void) {
    printf("Hello world!\n"); // print mESSAGE

}
```

I've seen codes that lowercase to uppercase strings or chars and vice versa for example with functions help, but is there any similar or any other code that does this work for comments? :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
 
int main()
{
    char s[1000];  
  
    printf("Enter  the string: ");
    gets(s);
    
        
    strlwr(s);         
 
    printf("string in lowercase ='%s'\n",s);
    
    return 0; 
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any way? Yes: write a parser that rewrites the file according to your rules. But detecting commented code isn't as trivial as it might seem.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, whoever told you to use `gets` cannot be trusted as reliable source of learning C. The teacher/book who told you to use it needed to be retired some 20 years ago.

Comment: I have to do this as a project and that's exactly my problem: the compiler & the compiled code know nothing about the comments. But I need to somehow make them be able to be recognized and make them from uppercase to lowercase and vice versa. I still haven't found something with ASCII or Flex

Comment: If you have to do this as a project, work in small steps. First read a file and create a new one exactly the same. Next detect the `//`  and invert the case of the rest of the line. Next work with `/*comments*/`, detecting where they begin and end. But a difficulty is that the comment opener might be inside a string literal, so you need to filter through them too. And a terminating quote mark might be an 'escaped' literal quote, and so it goes.

Comment: Is that a C beginner's project or some compiler generation project? Switching between upper and lower case is one thing. Parsing code properly to identify comments reliably is a completely different story.

Comment: It's more like university progress (we are now learning how to work on VM/linux with the help of C programming language) but I couldn't find anything in books nor something useful for Comments on google, just lowercase and uppercase codes for strings or chars.

Comment: Programming is not calling library routines and looking things up. A programmer does not perform a task like “Write a point-of-sale system” by doing a web search for how to write a point-of-sale system. To learn programming, you learn elementary techniques and common library routines, and you learn algorithms for building upon the elementary techniques to make more complex software. Before being assigned a project to change the case of text in comments, you will have been taught information about reading characters and processing them in various ways…

Comment: … To do the assignment, you need to use the techniques the class has covered previously to build the program out of multiple steps.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the C syntax is a non trivial task. Here is a small program that strips comments from a C source file. You can modify it to change comments. Hint: start by changing comments to uppercase, then transpose the case of characters.

This program reads the file contents one byte at a time, via a function `getcpp` that handles the infamous line continuation sequence, `\` immediately followed by a newline, and maintains the line number for error messages.

The `main()` function parses the C syntax including comments, characters constants and string literals. It supports most of the syntax but does not handle trigraphs (an obsolete feature of historical interest only).

As posted, it removes all comments, replacing them with a space or a newline as appropriate.  Study the code and see how you can modify it for your purpose.  Learning by example is a good method, once you get the program to do what you need, you can try and rewrite one from scratch to hone your skills and make progress.

Here is the code:

```
/* strip C comments by chqrlie */

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* read the next byte from the C source file, handing escaped newlines */
int getcpp(FILE *fp, int *lineno_p) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) == '\\') {
        if ((ch = getc(fp)) != '\n') {
            ungetc(ch, fp);
            return '\\';
        }
        *lineno_p += 1;
    }
    if (ch == '\n')
        *lineno_p += 1;
    return ch;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = stdin, *ft = stdout;
    const char *filename = "<stdin>";
    int ch, lineno;

    if (argc > 1) {
        if ((fp = fopen(filename = argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file %s: %s\n",
                    filename, strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (argc > 2) {
        if ((ft = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open output file %s: %s\n",
                    argv[2], strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    lineno = 1;
    while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF) {
        int startline = lineno;
        if (ch == '/') {
            if ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) == '/') {
                /* single-line comment */
                //putc('/', ft);
                //putc('/', ft);
                while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
                    // Do something with the comment character
                    //putc(ch, ft);
                }
                if (ch == EOF) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unterminated single line comment\n",
                            filename, startline);
                    break;
                }
                putc('\n', ft);  /* replace comment with newline */
                continue;
            }
            if (ch == '*') {
                /* multi-line comment */
                int lastc = 0;
                //putc('/', ft);
                //putc('*', ft);
                while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF) {
                    // Do something with the comment character
                    //putc(ch, ft);
                    if (ch == '/' && lastc == '*') {
                        break;
                    }
                    lastc = ch;
                }
                if (ch == EOF) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unterminated comment\n",
                            filename, startline);
                    break;
                }
                putc(' ', ft);  /* replace comment with single space */
                continue;
            }
            putc('/', ft);
            /* keep parsing to handle n/"a//"[i] */
        }
        if (ch == '\'' || ch == '"') {
            int sep = ch;
            const char *const_type = (ch == '"') ? "string" : "character";

            putc(sep, ft);
            while ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) != EOF) {
                putc(ch, ft);
                if (ch == sep)
                    break;;
                if (ch == '\\') {
                    if ((ch = getcpp(fp, &lineno)) == EOF)
                        break;
                    putc(ch, ft);
                }
                if (ch == '\n') {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unescaped newline in %s constant\n",
                            filename, lineno - 1, const_type);
                    /* This is a syntax error but keep going as if constant was terminated */
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ch == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: unterminated %s constant\n",
                        filename, startline, const_type);
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        putc(ch, ft);
    }
    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose(fp);
    if (ft != stdout)
        fclose(ft);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why consider `// .... EOF` an error?  Looks OK to me. (6.4.9 Comments)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: the messages are mostly warnings. The parser does not perform a complete syntax check. Here is the C Standard's definition of single line comments: **6.4.9 Comments** *Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters // introduce a comment that includes all multibyte characters up to, but not including, the next new-line character. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find the terminating new-line character.*... A single line comment without a terminating newline is at best inelegant.

Comment: It is interesting that the `//` comment ends _before_ and not including the `'\n'`.  LSNED.  Technically, all `//` comments then lack a terminating newline.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: yes, this way the single line comment (which the C Standard does not name this way) can be removed completely whereas the multi-line comment is replaced with a single space.

Comment: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71856237/how-do-i-uppercase-to-lowercase-and-vice-versa-comments-in-c#comment126983435_71858882) makes sense.

Comment: The phrase *The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find the terminating new-line character* is indeed somewhat clumsy since the contents cannot by construction contain a new-line character.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote and tested this program that does what you ask assuming that the only true C-comments either begin with `//` and end with `'\n'` or begin with `/*` and end with `*/`

It's not overly efficient as it only reads and writes one character at a time, but I think the code is pretty easy to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int args, char *argv[]){
  if(args != 3){ //Ensure the program was run with the proper number of arguments
    fprintf(stderr,"USAGE: %s <input file> <output file>\n",argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  FILE *in = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  FILE *out = fopen(argv[2],"w");
  if(!in || !out){ //Ensure both files opened successfully
    fprintf(stderr,in ? "File %s unopenable for writing\n" : "File %s unopenable for reading\n",in ? argv[2] : argv[1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  int first,second;
  second = fgetc(in);
  if(second == EOF) //Input file is empty
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  first = second;
  enum {line_comment,multiline_comment, string_text, non_comment} status = non_comment; //Keeps track of what type of text we're reading right now
  while((second = fgetc(in)) != EOF){
    switch(status){
        case line_comment: //Flip the case of every letter until we find a newline
            if(second == '\n' && first != '\\') //Allow escaped newlines
                status = non_comment;
            else if(second >= 'A' && second <= 'Z')
                second += 'a'-'A';
            else if(second >= 'a' && second <='z')
                second -= 'a'-'A';
            break;
        case multiline_comment: //Flip the case of every letter until we find "*/"
            if(first == '*' && second == '/') //We found the end of the comment
                status = non_comment;
            else if(second >= 'A' && second <= 'Z')
                second += 'a'-'A';
            else if(second >= 'a' && second <= 'z')
                second -= 'a'-'A';
            break;
        case string_text:
            if(second == '"' && first != '\\') //Look for end of string but ignore '\"' as those are allowed in strings
                status = non_comment;
            break;
        case non_comment: //Look for the two-character comment beginnings "//" and  "/*"
            if(first == '/'){
                if(second == '/')
                    status = line_comment;
                else if(second == '*')
                    status = multiline_comment;
            }
            else if(second == '"' && first != '\\') //Also check for the beginning of a string
                status = string_text;
            break;
    }
    fputc(first,out); //Write last round's possibly-modified char to the output file
    first = second;
  }
  fputc(first,out); //Output the last character of the file
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); //Close all open files
}
```

Comment: Also be aware that the `//`, `/*` and `*/` sequences can be separated by any number of escaped newlines :)